# WP7 - sockets architecture - How managed the sockets connection? Threads?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, windows-phone-7, user-interface, connection

I have to implement a async socket connection with a server to update text (like a chat) and shows this text in the screen of my app.

I have seen some examples about how I can implement this kind of sockets and it is not a difficult task...but I am looking for improve my program.

I am thinking that maybe I need manage the connection in background and I have no idea about how I can implement this task...Is it a good idea? manage the UI in one thread and the connection in other???

If someone could me oriented about this kind of task?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since classic socket I/O is blocking, you will definitely need to move your I/O code in a different thread since otherwise your UI thread will be blocked and unable to receive user input.

Ok, so you need another thread. The problem that appears now is that this thread cannot by itself update the UI if some input comes from the socket, because only the UI thread can do it. For this, you will need the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` call to forward updates to the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but could you suggest me which kind of threads can I use for this task?  I have been listening something about periodic task & resources intensive task....I think this kind of operations don't make sense to reach my goal...In a other hand I have been reading something about 3 ways differentes to implement task in background: System.Threading.Thread,  System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker and System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()...Could you give any  reference about which the best way to manage the socket in background? Thank

Comment: @Juan Pedro: For indefinite read from a socket I would use `System.Threading.Thread`. The thread pool is not meant for long-running I/O and the `BackgroundWorker` is generally useful for doing a time-consuming operations like database operations or downloads and can report progress, but is not generally used for indefinite waiting on a socket.

Comment: Thank you for your answers...Let me wait one day more before to set this post as a solved. I will like wait to hear the opinion of other user. Thank you anyway.